# How to populate selectbox using angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have two select box div for gettting scoredetails of Home teams and Awayteams both first and second innings

These two div are come in same page in my webpage with tabs button.

But when i am using this way my browser will hang without any error message in my log.

So I need same ng-model in both innings for code reusing.

But when i am using my browser will hang

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.score =
{
    "_id" : "586eb3a1d9913941d6494bf7",
    "battingDetails" : [
        {
            "battingId" : "1",
            "playerId" : "586150f2d99139510b4254bb"
        },
        {
            "battingId" : "2",
            "playerId" : "586150f2d99139510b4254b1"
        }
    ],
    "bowlingDetails" : [
        {
            "bowlingId" : "1",
            "bowlerId" : "586150f2d99139510b4254b2"
        }
    ]
}   

$scope.homePlayers = [{
    "id": "586150f2d99139510b4254bb",
    "name": "Sachin Tendulkar",
    "country": "India"
}, {
    "id": "586150f2d99139510b4254b1",
    "name": "Saurav Ganguly",
    "country": "India"
}];

$scope.awayPlayers =
[{
    "id": "586150f2d99139510b4254b2",
    "name": "Shane Watson",
    "country": "Aus"
}, {
    "id": "586150f2d99139510b4254b3",
    "name": "Steve Waugh",
    "country": "Aus"
}];

});
```

this is my corresponding html page

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

India batting vs Aus bowling<br>
    <div class="row">
        <span ng-repeat="battingDetail in score.battingDetails">
            <select ng-model="battingDetail.playerId">
            <option ng-repeat="eachhomePlayers in homePlayers" value="{{eachhomePlayers.id}}">{{eachhomePlayers.name}}</option>
        </select> 
        </span>
        <span ng-repeat="bowlingDetail in score.bowlingDetails">
            <select ng-model="bowlingDetail.bowlerId">
            <option ng-repeat="eachawayPlayers in awayPlayers" value="{{eachawayPlayers.id}}">{{eachawayPlayers.name}}</option>
        </select>
        </span>
        <button ng-click="update('home')">Update</button>
    </div>

Aus batting vs India bowling<br>
    <div class="row">
        <span ng-repeat="battingDetail in score.battingDetails">
            <select ng-model="battingDetail.playerId">
            <option ng-repeat="eachawayPlayers in awayPlayers" value="{{eachawayPlayers.id}}">{{eachawayPlayers.name}}</option>
        </select> 
        </span>
        <span ng-repeat="bowlingDetail in score.bowlingDetails">
            <select ng-model="bowlingDetail.bowlerId">
            <option ng-repeat="eachhomePlayers in homePlayers" value="{{eachhomePlayers.id}}">{{eachhomePlayers.name}}</option>
        </select>
        </span>
        <button ng-click="update('away')">Update</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

In here is code is working but when I am selecting first innings and after that selecting second innings, the selct box of first innings will clear.

Answer (score 0):

See your `ng-model="battingDetail.playerId"` ng-model is same for the two select fields. you should change separate name. because if you use same name when you select second dropdown it will affect to first dropdown, there have no object in first dropdown which you select on second. so it will be clear.

Copy and post this code instead of yours

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

India batting vs Aus bowling<br>
    <div class="row">
        <span ng-repeat="homeBattingDetail in score.battingDetails">
            <select ng-model="homeBattingDetail .playerId">
            <option ng-repeat="eachhomePlayers in homePlayers" value="{{eachhomePlayers.id}}">{{eachhomePlayers.name}}</option>
        </select> 
        </span>
        <span ng-repeat="homeBowlingDetail in score.bowlingDetails">
            <select ng-model="homeBowlingDetail .bowlerId">
            <option ng-repeat="eachawayPlayers in awayPlayers" value="{{eachawayPlayers.id}}">{{eachawayPlayers.name}}</option>
        </select>
        </span>
        <button ng-click="update('home')">Update</button>
    </div>

Aus batting vs India bowling<br>
    <div class="row">
        <span ng-repeat="awayBattingDetail in score.battingDetails">
            <select ng-model="awayBattingDetail.playerId">
            <option ng-repeat="eachawayPlayers in awayPlayers" value="{{eachawayPlayers.id}}">{{eachawayPlayers.name}}</option>
        </select> 
        </span>
        <span ng-repeat="awayBowlingDetail in score.bowlingDetails">
            <select ng-model="awayBowlingDetail.bowlerId">
            <option ng-repeat="eachhomePlayers in homePlayers" value="{{eachhomePlayers.id}}">{{eachhomePlayers.name}}</option>
        </select>
        </span>
        <button ng-click="update('away')">Update</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Where, I have

**home div**

> changed `battingDetail` to   `homeBattingDetail`
>
> changed `bowlingDetail` to   `homeBowlingDetail`

**away div**

> changed `battingDetail` to   `awayBattingDetail`
>
> changed `bowlingDetail` to   `awayBowlingDetail`

Comment: I seen, 
but i need same way because i add my score in same field name in my db
I add score first innings and second innings seperately with same structure
and when i fetching that it should be visible both

Comment: You need put separate name . then you get it and assign to the db model name. otherwise this problem will be continue

Comment: no Ji, same effect you check it that, when i change selectbox in seecond innings first innings selectbox will clear

Comment: any other way, if i change playerId and bowlerId in second innings it will solve but my db feld name is playerId and bowlerId.If i chnage means how to reassing while fetching and posting this db name

Comment: if i am using text box no issue happens instead of selectbox